# How do I render json in my react component?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have the following json file I am importing into my component:

```
import { beer, wine, spririts, alcopop } from '../../config/calculator.json';
```

How can I use the json in my `render`?

Depending upon what was chosen I would like to use the data for each element, if user clicks beer, then show data for beer. For example, how would I loop through 'sizes' in 'beer'? This is my code so far:

```
   {[drinkType].sizes.map((option, i) =>
          <div value={option.id} key={i}>
         {option}
          </div>
        )}
```

I would like to display the size name, pint, bottle, can etc

I get the error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
//calculator.json
{
    "beer": {
        "name": "Beer or cider",
        "sizes": {
            "568": {
                "name": "Pint",
                "size": 0.568,
                "id": "pint",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "beer_pint"
            },
            "440": {
                "name": "Can",
                "size": 0.44,
                "id": "can",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "beer_can"
            },
            "330": {
                "name": "Bottle",
                "size": "0.33",
                "id": "bottle",
                "max": "10",
                "icon": "beer_bottle_330"
            },
            "275": {
                "name": "Small bottle",
                "size": 0.275,
                "id": "smallBottle",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "beer_bottle_275"
            }
        },
        "strength": [4, 4.5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    },
    "wine": {
        "name": "Wine or champagne",
        "sizes": {
            "125": {
                "name": "Small glass",
                "size": 0.125,
                "id": "small",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "wine_small_glass"
            },
            "175": {
                "name": "Standard glass",
                "size": 0.175,
                "id": "std",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "wine_standard_glass"
            },
            "250": {
                "name": "Large glass",
                "size": 0.25,
                "id": "large",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "wine_large_glass"
            },
            "1000": {
                "name": "Bottle",
                "size": 1,
                "id": "bottle",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "wine_bottle"
            }
        },
        "strength": [9, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
    },
    "spirits": {
        "name": "Spirits or shots",
        "sizes": {
            "25": {
                "name": "Single",
                "size": 0.025,
                "id": "single",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "spirit_single"
            },
            "35": {
                "name": "Large single",
                "size": 0.035,
                "id": "lgSingle",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "spirit_large_single"
            },
            "50": {
                "name": "Double",
                "size": 0.05,
                "id": "double",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "spirit_double"
            },
            "70": {
                "name": "Large double",
                "size": 0.07,
                "id": "lgDouble",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "spirit_large_double"
            },
            "700": {
                "name": "Bottle",
                "size": 0.7,
                "id": "bottle700",
                "max": 3,
                "icon": "spirit_bottles"
            },
            "1000": {
                "name": "Bottle",
                "size": 1,
                "id": "bottle",
                "max": 3,
                "icon": "spirit_bottles"
            }
        },
        "strength": [37, 40]
    },
    "alcopop": {
        "name": "Alcopop",
        "sizes": {
            "275": {
                "name": "Small bottle",
                "size": 0.275,
                "id": "small",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "alcopops_small_bottle"
            },
            "330": {
                "name": "Standard bottle",
                "size": 0.33,
                "id": "std",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "alcopops_standard_bottle"
            },
            "750": {
                "name": "Large bottle",
                "size": 0.75,
                "id": "large",
                "max": 10,
                "icon": "alcopops_large_bottle"
            }
        },
        "strength": [5, 5.5]
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show a particular object or the entire json beer object

Comment: Depending which one was clicked - so if beer was clicked I would show, all sizes for beer

Comment: You import the JSON file as a variable, then in render, you manipulate the data. You need to use a for loop to iterate through it all :)

Comment: How do I loop through 'sizes' in beer?

Comment: I think your example is okay, the only thing missing, is that inside the `map` you should be returning the div generated.
```return (
    <div>...
    </div>
);```

Comment: @Willemoes i get the error cannot read property map of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.map does not work on objects like that,
map() is only for **Arrays**

Instead you can store the keys in array and use them, like,

```
    import jsonData from '../../config/calculator';
    ...
   //in constructor or any function
   let sizes;
   sizes={};
    for(let i of Object.keys(jsonData)){
         if(!sizes[i][0])sizes[i] = [];
         for(let j of Object.keys(i.sizes)){
           sizes[i].push(jsonData[i].sizes[j])
          }
      }
     this.setState({
         sizesArray:sizes
      })
```

Now you can use this.state.sizesArray.map to iterate over sizes, like,

```
  {this.state.sizes[drinkType].map((option, i) =>
          <div value={option.id} key={i}>
         {option}
          </div>
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, import your json inside the component:

```
import jsonData from '../../config/calculator'; //specify the appropriate location of the json file
```

Then you can access the "data" in your component in various ways. One way could be:

```
constructor() {
 this.state = {
  data: []
 }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({data: jsonData});
}
```

And accordingly, you can use this data(this.state.data).

Comment: Thanks, I keep getting the error,  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, any ideas?

Comment: You might be perform map on undefined object. first, check the state's data, and then use map in this way: this.state.data.map((data) =>{})

Comment: THanks for the reply, i just need to ouput property names of the object? Any ideas?

Comment: Ok.. did you updated your code with the above comments ? You getting any error now ?